# Is there a way to tell BPM of an audio playing on the computer in real time?

Tags: python

I completely understand that this is by no means easy. I basically want to create a code which takes the audio playing on the computer, samples it and outputs its BPM as a number. Is there any way it would be possible? I am not new to audio engineering, so I think the easiest would be to find the bass drum and count the beats, although as I just started programming, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask] and what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. We cannot recommend libraries or tools, nor can we design an entire program feature for you. " although as I just started programming" Then please try to learn to walk before running.